# GitHub Actions - Scheduled Container Rebuild On Latest Release Tag only

Tags: docker, security, github, containers, github-actions

I'm trying to setup scheduled container rebuilds on my latest release (git tag).

I'm already building containers on main branch and version tags, but i'd like to expand the version tags to be a scheduled rebuild to pickup base image security updates.  I can't figure out how to do scheduled actions on only the latest tag.

Suggestions welcome.  My example repository is [github.com/ruckc/container-openldap](https://github.com/ruckc/container-openldap).  I reuse this same workflow frequently, and just trying to improve it to handle base image updates.

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: ['main']
    tags:
      - 'v*'

env:
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  IMAGE_NAME: ${{ github.actor }}/openldap

jobs:
  build-and-push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up QEMU
        id: qemu
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2
        with:
          platforms: arm64,amd64

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Log in to the Container registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
        with:
          tags: |
            type=ref,event=branch
            type=ref,event=pr
            type=semver,pattern=version
            type=semver,pattern={{major}}.{{minor}}
          images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
          platforms: linux/arm64,linux/amd64
          cache-from: type=gha
          cache-to: type=gha,mode=max
```

Comment: See [`on.schedule`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onschedule).

Comment: On `schedule` event, you can checkout to latest tag and then the build will proceed from there.

Comment: Does the latest tag change its name? Or is the latest tag always the same, e.g. "`latest`". This is not clear to me from your question, because as @Azeem already commented, you can schedule and then always build on schedule (after some time and under some conditions Github will stop these, but this is all documented).

Comment: Please provide examples how your latest release git tags are named with your question.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your existing `on` events, you can add [`on.schedule`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onschedule) in your workflow.

On `schedule` event, you can build your container on the `latest` tag (or fetch the latest tag in a separate step and use it for the build).